# How to save state of Arraylist

Tags: android

I'm writing a simple todo List application. I am unclear on saving an applications state. İ just need the save state of ArrayList.

```
 ArrayList<CheckBox> alCheckbox = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
```

i tried to override **onSaveInstanceState** method. But i cant.

How can i save the state of ArrayList.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to save the data in a permanent fashion? Or just for configuration changes and restarts?

Comment: İ require persistent storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onSaveInstanceState is meant to be used for application restarts. For instance when the user changes the orientation on the screen. You want a permanent storage solution for data that should persist the application being launched, stopped, killed, etc... For a more permanent solution like SharedPreferences, Internal/External Storage, or SQLite Databases. Here's the tutorial on [Data Storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).